# Would it be possible to make a component which will disappear by mouseovering it only with CSS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to do that, but as show in this [demonstration](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVARG21UTFXU), it does not seem to work.

The CSS code:

```
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}

div:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

So do we have to use javascript for my purpose?

Comment: you could just add display: none on :hover?

Comment: I did. I think it is so in the demonstration link included.

Comment: ok sorry about that, use opacity: 0 or visibility: hidden

Comment: Once it's hidden there is nothing to hover so it appears again. Probably happening over and over but too rapidly to see the transition

Comment: OK. Thanks. Another question: How is this question off-topic?

Comment: Because code should be shown in the question itself. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your initial issue. Demos are helpful but only as support for what actually exists in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `opacity:0;` instead of `display:none;`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}
    
div:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<span>Hover over me!</span>
<div>I will show on hover</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually it would be "I will not show on hover" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. CSS is finnicky, and you have to understand the parent-child relationship first.

Make it so that when you hover over the parent, it hides the child.
The way you did it: if you hide the element, you will no longer be hovering over it, and therefore it reappears and the CSS can't decide what to do.

One more note: It will still spaz in this situation, if you use `display: none`, because it will change the size of parent. I used `visibility: hidden` to get around this.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVART8OA0CWY

`.hide_hover:hover span{ visibility: hidden; }` means that a `span`, with a parent of class `hide_hover`, when the parent is being hovered over, will be hidden.